# Opencv 2.4.3 How to Convert IPL_DEPTH_8U to IPL_DEPTH_32F?

Tags: opencv

```
char* filename1="1.bmp";  
IplImage* greyLeftImg= cvLoadImage(filename1,0);
char* filename2="2.bmp";
IplImage* greyRightImg= cvLoadImage(filename2,0); 

IplImage* greyLeftImg32=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),32,greyLeftImg->nChannels);//IPL_DEPTH_32F 
IplImage* greyRightImg32=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),32,greyRightImg->nChannels);
```

Always failed,said " Assertion failed (src.size == dst.size && dst.type() == CV_8UC(src.channels())) in unknown function"

I have searched for many methods , but none of them seems to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function to convert any `IplImage` to 32 bit float.

```
IplImage* convert_to_float32(IplImage* img)
{
    IplImage* img32f = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_32F,img->nChannels);

    for(int i=0; i<img->height; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<img->width; j++)
        {
            cvSet2D(img32f,i,j,cvGet2D(img,i,j));
        }
    }
    return img32f;
}
```

An important consideration is that for floating point images in OpenCV, only those can be visualized whose pixel values are from 0.0 and 1.0.
To visualize the floating point image, you have to scale the values from 0.0 to 1.0.

Here is an example for how to do this:

```
IplImage* img8u = cvLoadImage(filename1,0);

IplImage* img32f = convert_to_float32(img8u);

cvShowImage("float image",img32f); //Image will not be shown correctly
cvWaitKey(0);

cvScale(img32f, img32f, 1.0/255.0);

cvShowImage("float image normalized",img32f); //Image will be shown correctly now 
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple step to convert any gray scale 8 bit or 16 bit uint images in opencv to 32 bit floating type is like this...

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "E:\\Work_DataBase\\earth.jpg",0);
IplImage* out = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_32F, img->nChannels);

double min,max;

cvMinMaxLoc(img,&min,&max);

// Remember values of the floating point image are in the range of 0 to 1, which u 
// can't visualize by cvShowImage().......
cvCvtScale(img,out,1/ max,0);
```

Hope it is easy way...